# How do I plot the sum of two discrete time signals?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have x[n] = {1,2,2,1,4} and −1 ≤ n ≤ 5

How do I plot y[n] = x[n] + y[n-1]?
I am new to matlab, and am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried using the method in the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051407/how-can-i-plot-the-sum-of-two-discrete-signal but I don't really understand it and can't get it to work.

Comment: Is the 2nd term of the sum really y(n-1) or rather x(n-1)?

Comment: yes, the 2nd term is y(n-1)

Answer (score 0):

This question does not seem well posed.  Your vector for `n` in your first statement makes no sense (to me) in the context of your second statement.

If we ignore the first statement for `n`, your second statement appears to tell us how to build up a new value of `y` given `x` and given the previous previous of `y`.  That's fine.  You can easily solve for `y` with a `for` loop.

```
x = [1,2,2,1,4];   % this is your given input data
y = [];            % this is your output
for I=1:length(x)  % loop over each value of x
    if (I==1)      % the first time through is a special case
        %assume that the previous value of y is zero
        y(I) = x(I);  
    else
        %your given equation
        y(I) = x(I) + y(I-1);  
    end
end
y(:)  %display y to the screen
```

Comment: Thanks, it might have made more sense if I had said −1 ≤ n ≤ 5

Answer (score 0):

The function `y[n] = x[n] + y[n-1]` is the sum (or discrete integration) of the signal `x[n]`. You can therefore remove the loop using the MATLAB command `cumsum` and come up with

```
x = [1,2,2,1,4];
y = cumsum(x);
stem(y);             % plot y
```